# “ModuleBuildError: Undefined variable: "$base-spacing" when attempting to build Vue cli-3 app on Jenkins Server

Tags: jenkins, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

Stack:

- Vue CLI 3.0.0-beta.11
- Node 5.6
- Jenkins 2.7

I used VUE CLI 3 to build a simple proof-of-concept in Webstorm for work.  I had no issues building locally, and creating some simple vue components. So far, great experience.

One of my dev dependencies for my project is privately hosted package which contains the global styles for the entire company. Mostly, this package contains common vars, typography, structure code, etc. I was able to add the following to my vue.config.js in order to pull the scss files in and globally use them in my .vue files.  Works great locally using npm run serve or npm run build.

```
config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('normal').use('sass-loader')
    .tap(options =>
      merge(options, {
        data: '@import "~@myCorp/mycorp.ui.styles/shared/vars";' +
               '@import "~@myCorp/mycorp.ui.styles/shared/structure";' +
               '@import "~@myCorp/mycorp.ui.styles/shared/typography";'
      }))
```

It took me a while to get this working correctly, but this seems to work great using npm run serve. Also, npm run build outputs the correct files that work great in my CDN when I run the command locally, then manually upload the files.

The problem I have is when I try and execute npm run build while on my Jenkins CI box.  I have a Jenkins job that essentially runs the following:

```
npm install
npm run-script build-dev    
\\This just runs vue-cli-service build --mode dev
```

I'm consistently getting several of the following error:

```
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
    width: $base-spacing * 4;
      ^
    Undefined variable: "$base-spacing".
```

I get this error once for each of my components, and they each error on the first variable i'm using from my global scss files.  It seems the build is having issues loading the scss files, but I can't figure what would be different.

Like I said before, Webstorm has zero issue finding the files and including them in local builds, but as soon as I put them in Jenkins, it fails building.  I've tried importing the files in different ways, through a local scss import in my main.scss in my project, or even importing them directly in my main.js, but they don't get picked up by the loaders.

What am I missing?  Is there something different about paths that I need to take into account for CI/CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to beta-15, I was no longer to able to get this to work locally. I posted an issue to the cli githib: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1511

The correct answer is to not modify the sass-loader directly using tap, but to rather use the built in css.loaderOptions.sass block in vue.config.js. Thus, my vue.config.js turned into this:

```
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: '@import "~@myCorp/mycorp.ui.styles/shared/vars";'
      }
    }
  }
```

Works great!